# How to skew a tiled map in canvasengine

Tags: javascript, html

I use the canvasengine to program my HTML5 game. I have implemented a tiled map which works so far, but is static.

Now i want the player to have the ability to move around. So I thought: "OK, I use the canvasengine skew command". This works:

```
canvas.Scene.new ({
name: "tutorial",
materials: {
    images: {
        dg_edging232: "/maps/tilesets/dg_edging232.gif"
    }
},
ready: function(stage) {

    this.el = this.createElement();
    var tiled = canvas.Tiled.new ();
    tiled.load(this, this.el, "/maps/tutorial.json");
    tiled.ready(function() {
        var tile_w = this.getTileWidth(),
                tile_h = this.getTileHeight(),
                layer_object = this.getLayerObject();
        stage.append(this.el);
    });



},
render: function(stage) {
    canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.Left);
    canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.Right);
    canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.Up);
    canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.Down);


    stage.refresh();
}
});
```

Now, I'd like to do something like this:

```
canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.left,this.el.x--);
```

But I can't get it to work with the syntax above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with this libarary, but it looks like you might want to move the `keyDown` calls you have in render to `ready`, and on render, test for whether the key is pressed and move the sprite accordingly.

```
ready: function () {
  // ... your ready code

  // It's not clear from the docs, but it appears like you need to call
  // keyDown for each input to register it, even if you're passing no callbacks.
  // However, I'm guessing here.  This may not be necessary.
  canvas.Input.keyDown(Input.Left);
  // ... and so on for each direction
},

render: function () {
  // every frame test if the key is down, and update the sprite accordingly
  if (canvas.Input.isPressed(Input.Left)) this.el.x--;
  // ... and so on for each direction

  stage.refresh();
}
```